# Difference between plm and lm in statistical model

Tags: r, database, statistics, lm, plm

I have a data frame that has two variables on some personal characteristics; Y and X and the variable my_name that identifies name, where a grocery is chosen. What is the difference between the two following commands?

```
plm(Y~X, data=home, model = "within")
lm(Y~X+my_name, data=home)
```

Comment: Surely the first step should have been to read the documentation for these functions. Please do read both `?lm` and `?plm` (after of course loading the package that has the plm function.) Then you will be in a better postion to pose a question, hopefully using one of the datasets in the relevant help pages.

Comment: The function plm() estimates a within (also sometimes called a fixed effects) regression model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_effects_model. The function lm() esitmates a linear regression model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression.

Comment: Check the vignettes, they provide extended explanations: `vignette(package = "plm")` or `browseVignettes()` for a HTML list. The introductory vignette for plm have a topic explaining the difference